# Velocity Field line

Tags: python, python-2.7

[image]
I wrote code to plot the velocity field line of the image above, but somehow the result turns out to be a total mesh of darkness. Can someone give me a help? Here is my code.

```
x = linspace(-45,-15,1500)
y = linspace(-3,9,600)
quiver(x,y,Vx,Vz)
```

Vx and Vz are from the hdf5 data and their shapes are (600L,1500L). Or, is there a way to plot the vector field when x from -25 to -30 and z from -5 to -1?

The image of darkness is as follows:
[image]

I then tried code

```
x, y = numpy.meshgrid(numpy.linspace(-45,-15,1500), numpy.linspace(-3,9,600))
quiver(x[::20, ::20],y[::20, ::20],Vx[::20, ::20],Vz[::20, ::20],color='r',angles='xy',
       scale_units='xy',scale=9000000)
```

And the image looks like this 
[image]